# Restore GLACIER Object to S3 Standard Tier

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm working on a code that will restore objects from Glacier. The tier we will use is Standard.
I'm following this doc:

[Bot3 documentation on client.restor_object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html?highlight=restore_object#S3.Client.restore_object)

See also this example from github account: https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/380

This code is working without the Tier option in RestoreRequest.

```
 import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('datasets-imported-imdb')
for obj_sum in bucket.objects.all():
    if obj_sum.key == 'testfile.mov':
        print(f'file being restored {obj_sum.key}')
        resp = bucket.meta.client.restore_object(
            Bucket=obj_sum.bucket_name,
            Key=obj_sum.key,
            RestoreRequest={'Days': 1,'Tier': 'Standard'}    
        )
    else:
        print(f'file not being restored {obj_sum.key}')
```

This is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    resp = bucket.meta.client.restore_object(
  File "/home/alex_anadon/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/alex_anadon/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 676, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (MalformedXML) when calling the RestoreObject operation: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation shows:

```py
response = client.restore_object(
    Bucket='string',
    Key='string',
    VersionId='string',
    RestoreRequest={
        'Days': 123,
        'GlacierJobParameters': {
            'Tier': 'Standard'|'Bulk'|'Expedited'
        },
    ...
```

Therefore, you should use:

```py
        resp = bucket.meta.client.restore_object(
            Bucket=obj_sum.bucket_name,
            Key=obj_sum.key,
            RestoreRequest={'Days': 1, 'GlacierJobParameters': {'Tier': 'Standard'}}
        )
```

Comment: It seems there's 2 different tiers in the documentation :  GlacierJobParameters (dict) --
S3 Glacier related parameters pertaining to this job. 

Tier (string) -- [REQUIRED]
Retrieval tier at which the restore will be processed.

Tier (string) --
Retrieval tier at which the restore will be processed.       ¿Why is that? I'll use the one you suggest. Thank you.

Comment: Ha, you're right! I have no idea of the difference between them. It mentions `OutputLocation` for one of them, so there might be different ways to restore the objects (eg in-place vs copied elsewhere), but I couldn't see an explanation of that either.